# How to check the existence of a column in the Postgres database I am connected to in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using postgres in Python with the library `psycopg2`. After connecting to a database, I am trying to check if a table with a given name exists. In postgres, I am doing this with the following lines:

```
\connect myDB
select exists(select * from pg_tables where schemaname='public' AND tablename='mytable';)
```

This works if the table exists but also if it doesn't.
In python I am doing this with the following lines:

```
import psycopg2 as pg
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT;
from psycopg2 import sql;

conn = pg.connect(user='postgres', host='localhost', password="pwd");
conn.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT);
conn.autocommit = True
sql_table_check = sql.SQL("select exists(select * from pg_tables where schemaname='public' AND tablename={});")\
        .format(sql.Identifier("mytable"));
cur = conn.cursor()
```

but this is returning the error

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "mytable" does not exist
LINE 1: ...m pg_tables where schemaname='public' AND tablename="mytable");
```

because such table has not been created yet.

What is the correct way to check if a column exists in psycopg2?

**EDIT**

Note that I would like to check the existence of the table in the database I am connected to, I don't mind if it exists in another database.

Comment: Why not `select count(*) AS tbl_ct from pg_tables where schemaname='public' AND tablename='mytable'` and then test for `tbl_ct > 0`? Don't use `sql.Identifier` for the table name. It is a value not an identifier.

Comment: Shall I format the string as `%s`?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My comment as an answer:

```
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=production host=localhost user=postgres")
tbl_sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname='public' AND tablename= %s"
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(tbl_sql, ('cell_per',))
cur.fetchone()
(1,)

cur.execute(tbl_sql, ('cell_p',))
cur.fetchone()
(0,)
```

Comment: There is a problem with this code: if a table with the same name exists in another database but not in the database I am connected to, your answer seems to be returning that the table exists. Also, how can I run this query directly on postgres?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi.  `pg_tables` only shows tables for the database you are running the query in.  To run directly in `psql` do: `SELECT count(*) FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname='public' AND tablename= <some_table>` or are you asking for something else?

Comment: @AdrianKavler From the results I am getting it does not seem so.

Comment: What is the query you are running and what is result? If you are getting a count > 0 then that table is in the database.

Comment: `tbl_sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname='public' AND tablename= %s"`; `cursor.execute(tbl_sql, ('myTable',))`; `cursor.fetchone()`. The problem is that it is returning `1` but `myTable` is not a table of the database I am connected to (`production` in the examples), but it is a table of another database.

Comment: Then either you are connected to another instance of Postgres that does have it or it is in the `production` database. `pg_tables` will only show tables in the database it is run in. To verify in `psql -d production` do :`\dt myTable` and `\dt "myTable"`

Comment: Ok, there was a missing parameter in the `connect` method: I was missing `dbname` parameter, sorry. BTW also `SELECT exists(SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname='public' AND tablename= %s)` is working.

Answer (score 0):

so you can go over error by using `try` and `except` to continue

```
sql_table_check = sql.SQL("select exists(select * from pg_tables where schemaname='public' AND tablename={});")\
        .format(sql.Identifier("mytable"));
try:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    print('Table exists')
except:
    print('Table does not exist')
```

*Edited based on comment*

you can also catch the error to check it later by

```
sql_table_check = sql.SQL("select exists(select * from pg_tables where schemaname='public' AND tablename={});")\
        .format(sql.Identifier("mytable"));
try:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    print('Table exists')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print('Table does not exist')
```

for example, and simply, if we try:

```
try:
    a = 5 / 0
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

We will get output

```
division by zero
```

you can get the exact format string through debugging `e` content in the exception part.

so we can then, use this to identify the error, to be used again like:

```
try:
    a = a / 0
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    if e.args[0] == 'division by zero':
        print('it is division by zero Error')
    else:
        raise(e)
```

so if the error is not the intended one the other error will raise.

you may get the error exception from `psycopg2` documentation as that for python in  `https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html`

as in the follwoing code:

```
try:
    a = 5 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('it is division by zero Error')
```

so we get:

```
it is division by zero Error
```

but when we have another error like:

```
try:
    a = 5 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('it is division by zero Error')
```

we get the other error

```
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

Comment: I don't think this is robust because other unrelated exceptions might be generated